# symfony3 entity form validation not working

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

even doing copy/paste of this constraits, nothing hapens, i have disabled the html validations also, this is the code : twig:

```
{{form_start(form, {'action':'', 'method':'POST'})}}
{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
{{form_end(form)}}
```

here the class:

```
class Curso {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\MaxLength(15)
 * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $titulo;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 2,
 *      max = 50,
 *      minMessage = "Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
 * )
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 * @ORM\Column(name="descripcion", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $descripcion;

/**
 * @var float
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="float")
 */
private $precio;

/**
 * Get id
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @return int
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set titulo
 *
 * @param string $titulo
 *
 * @return Curso
 */
public function setTitulo($titulo) {
    $this->titulo = $titulo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titulo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitulo() {
    return $this->titulo;
}

/**
 * Set descripcion
 *
 * @param string $descripcion
 *
 * @return Curso
 */
public function setDescripcion($descripcion) {
    $this->descripcion = $descripcion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get descripcion
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescripcion() {
    return $this->descripcion;
}

/**
 * Set precio
 *
 * @param float $precio
 *
 * @return Curso
 */
public function setPrecio($precio) {
    $this->precio = $precio;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get precio
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getPrecio() {
    return $this->precio;
}
}
```

can you tell me what is wrong? sorry about my english, i'm a little rusty :)!!!

Comment: Are you trying to validate your form or not? Why do you include `{'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}`?

Comment: @Chausser - wouldn't he still reasonably expect the framework to validate server-side, even with the `novalidate` option passed? @Pablo - can you include the `CursoType` form, and maybe the controller method that's handling the requests/responses for this action?

Comment: @CameronHurd You are correct, the novalidate option should only disable the HTML validation but the server should still do the validation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your `app/config.yml` and make sure that the you have annotations enabled for validation

```
framework: 
    ...
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```